# Objective C Editor Placeholder in source file when calling the method

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to translate one of my Swift apps into Objective C in order to learn that syntax as Swift apparently is not enough these days, unfortunately.

This is my method declaration:

```
- (void)getWeatherDataFromURL:(NSString *)url params:(NSString *)parameters {

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", url, parameters];
    NSLog(@"GETTING DATA FROM %@", urlString);

}
```

I have the following variables declared in the ViewController:

```
NSString *WEATHER_URL = @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
NSString *APP_ID = @"my_secret_api_key";
```

It seems to be accepted by XCode however the problem arises when I am trying to call the function:

```
[self getWeatherDataFromURL:WEATHER_URL params:APP_ID];
```

I get the following error:
**Editor placeholder in source file**

I have searched StackOverflow however all answers came up with Swift and not Obj-C

Apparently CMD + SHIFT + K did the magic. Xcode is buggy and it turns out there was nothing wrong with the code. However, I believe that the answer below will help other programmers having a problem like on the screenshot.

Comment: that has to be at some other place, not in the shown code snippet.

Comment: Where? I have added the function declaration to the header file as well. Could you explain, please? I am coming from the Swift world and never had such an error.

Comment: your url is `"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"` and after you add your app_id. it will like this way --> `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherYOURAPPID`

Comment: That is not the case I am using NSURLComponents query on the base URL and the params. There seems to be a weird XCode bug as the error seems to went away without touching it.

Comment: to connect params with url you need to combine with `?` , `&` , etc.. like `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APP_ID`

Comment: @NiravKotecha please look at my comment above. NSURLComponents is adding the ? as the params is used as a query. It works as I am getting the JSON back from the Weather API :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not due to Swift or Obj-c language. You have placeholder in your code. Check you don't have any gray placeholders like this:
[image]

Comment: I don't have any, as you can see I am strictly inserting the variable names to the function call. Weirdly enough my error has gone away automatically and it works after cleaning my project. Maybe it was just an XCode 10 Bug

Comment: @ADProgress that is the lesson to be learnt: before spending any time googling or even asking a question "clean" the xcode project. The IDE is sooo unbearably buggy :D

Comment: @luk2302 So true. Often obvious solutions come last to our minds.